# Pass argument to bash script with expect and SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, grep

I was trying to write some remote control script so I can grep some key words when tailing.

```
$ ./myscript.sh somekeyword
```

I expect it could log on the remote machine and run

```
$ tail -f /tmp/log/mylog.log | grep "somekeyword"
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no root@myhost
#use correct prompt
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "mypassowrd\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "tail -f \/tmp\/log\/mylog.log | grep \"$1\"\r"
interact
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of passing simulating an interactive session i would:

- setup ssh key based authentication - this removes the need of entering the password
- then use:

  ssh root@kroute "logread \| grep asd"